# How to get the data using simple_html_dom.php?

Tags: php

I want to get the data from the tag.

```
<div class="module question_card_categories  jsparams js-question_card_categories">
```

for this i create the code like this

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html("http://$a");
$tag = $html->find('div[class=module question_card_categories  jsparams js-question_card_categories]', 0);echo $tag;
 ?>
```

but sir nothing happen .
Plz help  me on this.
i try multiple time but result is zero.nothing is displaying.

Comment: `$a` was the source file ?

Comment: yes it is sorce file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the content by

```
$Content = file_get_contents($url);
```

Then explode it by

```
$Head = explode( '<div class="module question_card_categories  jsparams js-question_card_categories">' , $Content );
```

And explode it till the `</div>` by

```
$Body = explode("</div>" , $Head[1] );
```

So, If this is your html file

```
<div class="module question_card_categories  jsparams js-question_card_categories">Hellow Here i am </div>>
```

You can get the content by

```
<?php
$url = 'Yourfile.html';
$Content = file_get_contents($url);
$Head = explode( '<div class="module question_card_categories  jsparams js-question_card_categories">' , $Content );
$Body = explode("</div>" , $Head[1] );
echo $Body[0];
```

**Result :**

Hellow Here i am

Here is the [Eval](https://eval.in/392738)

### Update :

As the user want to get the categories of [this url](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_verb_of_receipt)

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_verb_of_receipt';
$Content = file_get_contents($url);
$Head = explode( '<ul class="categoryMenu categories">' , $Content );
$Body = explode("</ul>" , $Head[1] );
echo $Body[0];
```

Comment: Are you sure you given the correct path, Bcoz it works great in my local machine :)

Comment: http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_verb_of_receipt i want to get the category from this url

Comment: You want this one ? `English Language
Grammar
Languages and Cultures
Literature & Language
Parts of Speech` ?

Comment: I have updated the answer, which gets the categories from the url you given ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could get the content of the div as:

```
$tag = $html->find('div[class=module question_card_categories  jsparams js-question_card_categories]', 0);

echo  htmlspecialchars($tag); //shows you the tag and content

echo  $tag->innertext; //shows the text within the div
```

[See the manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Comment: What is the of value $a ? Please edit  your post and show the current code